# Can I move my Dock to the left side of my right monitor?

Tags: macos, display, dock

I have set up a two-monitor display, with my laptop on the left and my main screen on the right. I like having the Dock on the left side, but it's on the left of the left monitor, and as such it's too far to the left.

In the Dock settings, I only have the choice of Left (left side of left monitor), Bottom (bottom of left monitor), or Right (right side of right monitor). Is there any way I can set it to the left side of the right monitor?

Comment: A non-Apple suggestion would be [DragThing](http://www.dragthing.com/english/about.html) which is a Dock substitute that's been going since before the Dock existed. Can be pinned to anywhere, any screen. Not free, but I wouldn't be without it. No affiliation, just been using it since 1995 !

Answer (score 24):

I too have tried to have this setup, looking in display settings the closest thing that worked was this. It's not perfect but it does the job! Rearrange the left screen so that the screens meet at diagonals.

[image: System Preferences > Displays > Arrangement]

Comment: This is working

Comment: Unfortunate that we have to hack it this way, but it works (10.14)

Answer (score 9):

I've managed to achieve it with a help of [Wraparound](https://www.digicowsoftware.com/detail?_app=Wraparound) app (Free). It wraps mouse around your monitors so you can setup you monitors arrangement so the monitor you want your dock to be on would be first (if you want dock on left) or last (if you want it on right) and then just wrap mouse movement horizontally.

Here is example of my monitor arrangement before

[image: arrangement before Wraparound use]

and this is after

[image: arrangement after Wraparound use]

and here's how Wraparounds settings look

[image: Wraparounds settings]

so in the end my real setup looks like this

[image: real world monitor arrengement]

The only thing that doesn't work is dragging window from middle monitor to the left, it seems to work for an instant but then gets teleported back. But I'm using [Spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/) app (Free) to manage windows and I use a shortcut to move windows between monitors so that's not a problem for me at all.

Comment: I'm on 10.13.6 and Wraparound also worked for me. I have a secondary monitor on the right, but I wanted the dock to stay in the right edge of the left monitor. Wraparound made this possible!

Comment: If you drag-and-drop while moving the mouse quickly you can manage to drag from the middle monitor to the left before the teleporting action takes effect. I think of it like throwing the window.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I don't think that you can. OS X likely sees both the MacBook's display and the external monitor as one screen. Since you can't normally put the Dock in the middle of the screen, I doubt that you can put it on on the left side of the right monitor.

Comment: There should be a sign outside of Apple HQ that reads "Unfortunately, I don't think that you can." This is the correct answer to most MacOS-related questions.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

First, set the primary monitor:

- Open System Preferences
- Choose Displays
- Select the Monitors tab
- Drag the small white bar that appears on the graphic of your screen to the screen where you want the dock to reside. In this case, from the left to the right screen.
- Your screens will blank out briefly and the dock should appear where you want it.

Also:

- Back in System Preferences, select Mission Control
- Select "Displays have Separate Spaces"

Doing the second list may actually put the dock on both screens, if that was more convenient for you.

<sup>* I, unfortunately, don't have access to my other monitors to confirm this so the points may be general.</sup>

Comment: This is not working, when you have a monitor left of your main monitor (the one you dragged the bar to) and you position your dock left, your left monitor will be the one displaying the dock no matter what. That was the original problem of this question.

Comment: The white bar determines which monitor is considered "primary". It has no effect on where the Dock resides. "Displays have Separate Spaces" is the default setting on High Sierra. I did not try turning that option off because it would have required a logout.